# Server hacked, apache2 log contains get with a bash command

Tags: php, apache2

Today, I see this line in my access.log:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx - - (10/Dec/2016:xx:xx:xx +xxxx] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 XXXXX "-" "() { :;}; /bin/bash ... "
```

I don't understand how this get works, **what is the "() { :;}; /bin/bash ... " access log substring? This isn't the get argument? How did the hacker inject this string with the get request?**

I want reproduce a similar get for check if the /bin/bash has been executed or not, example:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx - - (10/Dec/2016:xx:xx:xx +xxxx] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 XXXXX "-" "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"touch /tmp/foo.txt \""
```

Comment: impressive! Did it succeed in creating `/tmp/foo.txt`?

Comment: I must know how I use the "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"touch /tmp/foo.txt \"" 'argument(?)' in the get request :) I don't know how I must build a similar get for reproduce this attack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the shellshock/bashdoor bug.

- [Shellshock (software bug)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) (wikipedia page)
- [Worrying httpd access logs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85440/worrying-httpd-access-logs)
- [How do I secure Apache against the Bash Shellshock vulnerability?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68146/how-do-i-secure-apache-against-the-bash-shellshock-vulnerability)

Comment: Thank you for the attack name and links :) I could reproduce the attack via this shell command : curl -A "() { ;;}; /bin/bash -c \"touch /tmp/foo.faa\"" 127.0.0.1. The strange string is the user agent ! But luckely, this command wasn't created the foo.faa file, I deduced that my server did not get hacked.